# Mensaje de exito con sweet alert en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas estoy haciendo un login en el cual uso el usuario y contraseña para ingresar pero al momento de ingresar quiero  que aparesca un mensaje de exito pero con un sweet alert y aparesca el usuario pero noce como implementarlo en mi codigo estoy usando sql server en asp.net en c#

```
 public ActionResult Login()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Login(string usuario, string contraseña, string notificationType)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario))
            {
                BolsasContext db = new BolsasContext();
                var user = db.Empleados.FirstOrDefault(e => e.usuario == usuario && e.contraseña == contraseña);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.usuario, true);

                    ViewBag.Mensaje = "Bienvenido(a): " + user.usuario;


                    return RedirectToAction("IndexEmpleado", "Home");

                }
                else
                {

                    return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "No reconocemos tus datos" });
                }
            }
            else
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Llena todos los campos para poder iniciar secion" });

        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma facil podrias generar codigo javascript en el action para que la view al renderizar el html ejecute esa funcionalidad mostrando el alerta

Por ejemplo, podrias poner el mensaje en el ViewBag

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string usuario, string contraseña, string notificationType)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario))
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Llena todos los campos para poder iniciar secion";
        return View();
    }

    BolsasContext db = new BolsasContext();
    var user = db.Empleados.FirstOrDefault(e => e.usuario == usuario && e.contraseña == contraseña);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "No reconocemos tus datos";
        return View();
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.usuario, true);

    ViewBag.Mensaje = "Bienvenido(a): " + user.usuario;


    return RedirectToAction("IndexEmpleado", "Home");
}
```

entonces en el javascript de la view de login puedes validar si el ViewBag tiene algun mensaje que mostrar y eso lo asignas el sweet alert

```
<script>

    @if(ViewBag.ErrorMensaje != null){
        Swal.fire(
        '@ViewBag.ErrorMensaje',
        '',
        'success');
    }

</script>
```

Ademas trata de programar ante lo afirmativo en los if

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu buscas es https://sweetalert2.github.io/ Para hacer uso de estas cajas popup requieres descargar esta librería. Colocarla en la carpeta javascript o la que tu decidas.

Después la añades en la página .html, .cshtml o .aspx de tu aplicación:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Supongo que debe ser login.

Hay varios ejemplos que te pueden servir, como este:

```
Swal.fire({
  position: 'top-end',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Has logrado guardar tus avances.',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
```